# Sum of all elements that solve $z^n* = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $n>1$ be a fixed positive integer and let

$H=\{z \in\Bbb{C} |z^n=1\}$

Prove that the sum of all elements of $H$ is $0$.

I've been struggling on this question for far too long for how simple it seems. I've tested a few explicit cases $n=2,3,4$ just imagining each solution as a vector in the complex plane, and just doing vector addition, and amazingly enough it works(what a surprise). But I am just unsure how to prove the general case...

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This results from *Vieta's relations* for polynomial equations.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of the set $H$ can be written in the form $\zeta^k$, where $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ and $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$. Therefore the sum is
$$ 1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\dots+\zeta^{n-1}=\frac{1-\zeta^n}{1-\zeta}=0 $$
since $\zeta^n=1$.

Another proof is that the sum of the elements of $H$ is equal to the negative of the coefficient of $z^{n-1}$ in the polynomial $z^n-1$, hence is zero.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks. I've been working in polar form for the rest of the question (it's multiple parts). Would a similar proof work using polar form?

Comment: You mean with sines and cosines? That seems fairly painful.

Comment: Ye, exactly :p. For the explicit cases I tried I just summed *z^(l)* with *z^(n-l)* each time and it worked out very nicely for low values of n... Can you think of a way of simplifying it without bludgeoning through long sums of sine functions? I've been stuck for a while now

Comment: Yes, use the method in my answer. Exponentials are much nicer to work with than trig functions.

Comment: Haha, alright. Thanks for the help!